# Syslog-NG is spooling messages

Tags: performance, tcp, syslog-ng, multi-threading

I am currently using Balabit's Syslog-NG to concentrate my IT logs and convey them in a remote server, *via* a TCP connection, which can allow one listening port only.

Thing is, my log volume is really important (about 15,000 messages/sec), and I can see that messages are being spooled in my disk ( I actually enabled `disk-buf-size(300G)` and `mem-buf-length(10M)`  in my `destination` TCP object.

Do you know if there is a way :

- to increase performance?
- To open several TCP sockets for `destination` objects (I tried `max_connections`, `threaded` etc. which didn't work)

**version of syslog-ng : 3.9**

Sample of syslog-ng.conf:

```
options {
  perm(0644);
  stats_freq(30)
  log_msg_size(65535)
  flush_lines(0);
  time_reap(10);
  threaded(yes);
  time_reopen(10);
  log_fifo_size(10M);
  chain_hostnames(off);
  use_dns(no);
  use_fqdn(no);
  create_dirs(yes);
  dir_perm(0755);
  keep_hostname(yes);
  keep-timestamp(yes);
};

...

destination dst_siem_port_1234 {
  tcp(
    "192.168.0.1"
    port(1234)
    disk-buffer( mem-buf-length(10M) disk-buf-size(300G) reliable(no) )
  );
};
log {source(mysrc); filter(f_myfilter); destination(dst_siem_port_1234); };
```

Sorty for typos in keyboard, copied screen-to-screen :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `flush_lines(100);` in the options so that client isn't sending one line at a time (at least that's my understanding of what happens when this is set to 0).